# Map Layout Elements In New Layer Automated Using Python

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, layouts, png, element

I was wondering if there was a way to put a title and integer data from an attribute table in a new layer created in Python. I was able to create a new layer using copy features, zoom to the selected features, and export the zoomed features in a map as a PNG all using arcpy, but I also wanted a title at the top and data from the attribute table of that specific layer in the map layout before it was exported. Is it possible to get all this automated using Python?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just do a [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) to get the specific field/record value and update layout default title text (you set this within a template map document), see sample code below.

```
import arcpy

# run search cursor here

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    if elm.text == "default title text":
        elm.text = myFieldValue # variable grabed from search cursor
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

If you want to export the map layout to png you may use [ExportToPNG](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000002s000000)

Comment: Would I be able to do this from a new layer in the same arcpy process? I created a new feature layer and I wanted that layer to be edited with title and density data from the attribute table and then exported to PNG all within the same script. Is that possible with the search cursor?

Comment: @Victor, Yes it should be possible.  If you post your script within your question I may be able to further assist.